I am updating the same image in ASP.NET Core MVC - but I am getting this error
I am updating the same image in ASP.NET Core MVC :
Here is my code:
public IActionResult UpdateProduct(IFormFile product_image, Product prd)
{
    string ImagePath = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath,"ProductImages",product_image.FileName);
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(ImagePath, FileMode.Create);
    product_image.CopyTo(fs);

    prd.product_image = product_image.FileName;

    _manicontext.tbl_product.Update(prd);
    _manicontext.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("FetchProduct");
} 

I am getting this error:

System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'red-kalenji-8771124.jpg' because it is being used by another process.'

How to solve this error?

Do you want to modify the image at sametime for multiple pages?

Did you have the image open in another window/application? If so close anything that might have the image open before you run the above code.
